# How to combine 1 bit data with 8 bit data?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, binary

I have a array that contains mostly 0:s and 1:s, but some values are up to 255. So I have to store them in UINT8. Is there a way I could store the 1:s and 0:s with just 1 bit? Should I separate the array into two?

This is a part of the array.

```
array([[[   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   1,    1,    1],
        [   0,    0,    1],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   1,    1,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0],
        [   4,    4,    4],
        [  12,   13,   10],
        [  19,   19,   19],
        [  25,   25,   23]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: If you *can* separate the bits from the bytes, then this could be more efficient. You would still need to gather the bits into bytes to actually store them or transmit them. If they are just values in your program, then don't bother.

Comment: If you want to save memmory you can use a sparse array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Comment: This sounds like it might be premature optimization to me, although as @SebastianR. said you could use sparse arrays.